# Taking the phone off charge

Tags: word-usage

We say "I put phone on to charge". So can removing the charging point that's connected to the phone (USB) be called:

> I took my phone off charge.  (Opposite to "I put my phone on charge")

Answer (score 1):

"I took my phone off charge." is a perfectly reasonable thing to say. It would be fully understood by any modern speaker of British English. I use this phrase myself.

As I have no experience of other English dialects I can't give a definite answer for them, but my guess would be that if not a common phrase it at least would be understood.

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial.